# How to predict when a storm will hit given current & historical barometric data?

Tags: calculus, meteorology

As a storm approaches, the barometric pressure gets lower. Suppose we have a barometer, we know a storm's approaching within the next 24 hours. We take measurements every second or two and have a calculator handy. Additionally, we have historical data that will tell us what the pressure will be when the storm hits. Can we use physics/calculus to predict when this storm will hit?

Comment: You should look up the history of chaos theory.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a simplified version of how weather predictions were made before computer modeling and satellites. Barometric pressure and wind direction & velocity readings were collected from a large number of weather stations on the ground, and mapped out onto a portion of a continent. Then, based on previous experience, the weather experts would study the resulting maps and make their best guesses on where & when the storm would hit and how hard it would hit. This method worked fairly well in regions where changes in weather were repetitive enough to support predictions (as for example, on the California coast during the wet season).

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to do this given just the pressure?

Comment: not very reliably. that's why wind speed and direction are included in the analysis.

Comment: :OK, so let's say we do have the windspeed and direction. What formulas would we use to get what we want?

Comment: oh man... I'm afraid you'll have to talk to someone who does this for a living.